# Firebase sendResetPasswordEmail firing twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to have a user enter their email address in a text field, and click a submit button to send them a reset link using firebase's reset method. Only issue is, I can get it to work one way, but it fires twice, and fires before the button is even clicked. I have a commented out function that should work, but isn't working for some reason. Any reason why the commented out one isn't working? Still new to react so any help is appreciated!

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getAuth, sendPasswordResetEmail } from "firebase/auth";

import '../scss/pages/ForgotPage.scss'

function ForgotPassword() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const auth = getAuth();


 //   const triggerResetEmail = async () => {
 //       await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
 //           .then(() => {
 //               navigate('/signin')   //   Issue, keep reseaching
 //           })
 //           .catch((error) => {
 //               const errorCode = error.code;
 //               const errorMessage = error.message;
//
 //           });
 //   }

    sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
        .then(() => {
            // Password reset email sent!
            navigate('/signin')
            // ..
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // ..
        });

    return (
        <div className='pageBackground'>
            <div className='loginContainer'>
                <div className="regForm-container sign-in-container">
                    <form className='regForm' action="/">
                        <h1 className='formHeader'>Enter your login email</h1>
                        <input className='loginInput' type="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={(a) => setEmail(a.target.value)} value={email} required />
                        <button className='ghost' onClick={() => sendPasswordResetEmail}>Reset</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="overlay-container">
                    <div className="overlay">
                        <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                            <h1 className='formHeader'>Don't sweat it</h1>
                            <h5 className='regP'>Forgetting a password happens to the best of us!</h5>
                            <h5 className='regP'>But just in case you remembered</h5>
                            <button className='ghost' onClick={() => navigate('/signin')}>Log In</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ForgotPassword;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling  sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email) in the function body of your functional component. Which means it will be called every time the component renders. Just like if you put `console.log("rendering")` in your function body.

```
const someFunction = () => {
    sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
};

and

<button onClick={someFunction} />
```

Comment: that makes sense. This works, but is there any reason that the .then() function isnt working? It wont navigate to the page I specified. It jumps to the landing page with a '?' at the end of the url

Comment: No idea. None of your router config is shown.